# Problema al descargar

Tags: laravel, imagen, descarga

Tengo un error, anteriormente habia descargado 1 archivo y me funciona, pero ahora quiero descargar 2 archivos con botones diferentes y me aparece el error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\vehiculosController::descargar(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($listvehiculos as $listado)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$listado['id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$listado['patente'] }}</td>
    <td>{{$listado['r_tecnica'] }}</td>
    <td>{{$listado['p_circulacion'] }}</td>
    <td>{{$listado['descripcion'] }}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="vehiculos/{{ $listado->img_p_circulacion }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="vehiculos/{{ $listado->img_r_tecnica }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <form method="POST" action="{{action('vehiculosController@destroy', $listado->id)}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('¿Esta Seguro?')">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
           </button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

, envio codigo:

```js
public function descargar($img_r_tecnica, $img_p_circulacion) 
{
  $pathtoFile = public_path().'/images_tecnica/'.$img_r_tecnica;
  $i_circulacion = public_path().'/images_circulacion/'.$img_p_circulacion;
  if ($pathtoFile) {
    return response() - > download($pathtoFile);
  }
  return response() - > download($i_circulacion);
}
```

```js
Route::get('vehiculos/{vehiculo}', 'vehiculosController@descargar') - > name('vehiculos.descargar');
```

PD: LAS IMAGENES ESTAN EN CARPETAS DIFERENTES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función en el Controlador espera dos parámetros `$img_r_tecnica, $img_p_circulacion`, y en la ruta solo estás tomando un parámetro `{vehiculo}`

Para resolverlo una opción puede ser pasarle el nombre de la carpeta ya desde los links:

```
<a href="{{ route('vehiculos.descargar', [ 'carpeta' => 'images_circulacion', 'imagen' => $listado->img_p_circulacion ]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</a>


<a href="{{ route('vehiculos.descargar', [ 'carpeta' => 'images_tecnica', 'imagen' => $listado->img_r_tecnica ]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</a>
```

Aceptar el nombre de la carpeta y el nombre del archivo como parámetros en la ruta:

```
Route::get('vehiculos/{carpeta}/{imagen}', 'vehiculosController@descargar')->name('vehiculos.descargar');
```

Y recibir los parámetros en la función del controlador:

```
public function descargar($carpeta, $imagen) 
{
  $pathtoFile = public_path($carpeta . '/' . $imagen);

  return response()->download($pathtoFile);
}
```

Comment: esta buena tu logica, lo realize y me aparece un error al descargar la img_r_tecnica el cual, al parecer se mezclan las rutas, este error es:

Comment: disculpa, lo había puesto al revés en los links. ahí lo edité

Comment: perdon, tenia algo escrito mal en un lado por eso me daba ese error, ahora el error es otro, al descargar imagen de rev tecnica, me manda a una pagina vacia (blanco) y no me descarga la img, este link me genera

Comment: http://localhost:8000/vehiculos/r_tecnica.jpg

Comment: el cual a mi parecer esta bien, pero no me aparece para guardar la imagen en mi PC

Comment: la url debería ser `localhost:8000/vehiculos/images_tecnica/r_tecnica.jpg`. Verifica que hayas copiado bien el codigo, pues `images_tecnica` no puede no aparecer en la url, pues está hardcodeado: `href="vehiculos/images_tecnica/{{ $listado->img_r_tecnica }}"`

Comment: si las tengo bien las revise, nose si sera por que antes del route que mostre en la pregunta, tambien tengo este?

Comment: Route::resource('vehiculos', 'vehiculosController');

Comment: sí, pon la ruta personalizada ante de la ruta resource

Comment: lo hice, pero aun asi, me tira en pagina en blanco con el link que te mencione, ahora me aparece al apretar cualquiera de los dos botones

Comment: limpia la cache de rutas: php artisan route:clear, vuelve a generarlo: php artisan route:cache, [limpia la cache del navegador](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects/304600#304600). Mira se te está tomando bien las rutas con: php artisan route:list

Comment: si, igual lo mismo (T_T) no me esta tomando la ruta

Comment: prueba usando el nombre de la ruta en los links `href="{{ route('vehiculos.descargar', ['carpeta'=>'images_tecnica', 'imagen'=>$listado->img_r_tecnica]); }}` y lo mismo para la otra

Comment: error de sintaxys syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Comment: hay esta el codigo amigo! me funciono gracias amigo!!!

Comment: <a href="{{ route('vehiculos.descargar', ['carpeta' => 'images_tecnica', 'imagen'=>$listado->img_r_tecnica]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">

Comment: edita tu repuesta!! gracias enserio!